# Cancel on Activity B an Alarm of AlarmManager created on Activity A

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I trying to cancel on ActivityB an Alarm that I had created on ActivityA.

I think the problem is that to cancel an Alarm the PendingIntent must be the same that was created, in this case, the context of PendingIntent was the ActivityA and since I'm trying to cancel this alarm and PendingIntent on ActivityB, when I create the PendingIntent on ActivityB I don't know how to use the context of ActivityA.this to cancel it.

Comment: Please post the code that you use to set the alarm and also the code you use to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link and tutorial it'll give you a better understanding of the usage and implementation of the Pending Intetns.

http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-pending-intent/

Answer (score 0):

in Class that you create alarm add below method

```
private static Context mContext;
public static Context getActivityAContext() {
     return Reminder.mContext;
 }
```

and in another activity use

```
   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    ActivityA.getActivityAContext(),
    receiverId,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: When I created the Alarm I used as context: ActivityA.this.
So on the mContext that you suggest I should use as:
mContext = ActivityA.this; ?
When I arrive at home I'll try it, seems to be a good solution. I had tried to create a static method on ActivityA to cancel alarm, but was not possiblem to pass as context ActivityA.this in a static method.

Comment: :( It didn't work to cancel the alarm... I had tried a lot of things but nothing worked :(